# Circle CI integration with salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, integration, circleci

We want to integrate Circle CI with salesforce for deployment, but the project is not sfdx project. Means the project structure which we have is like below :

-Main
   -src
      -classes
      -triggers
   -manifest
      -package.xml

Can we use the same above project to integrate with circle CI or do we need to create an another sfdx project?

Answer (score 1):

CircleCI doesn't know anything about Salesforce. It's just a CI harness for any build system. (There are some [orbs for SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/08/new-salesforce-apex-circleci-orb.html) that may help in your implementation, though).

You will presumably be using (you *should* be using) the SFDX CLI as your deployment tool inside your CircleCI jobs. SFDX can deploy both Metadata API-format source, as shown here, and Salesforce DX-format source. You'll simply need to include the appropriate commands (such as `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`) in your build scripts.

The position of your `package.xml` in a separate manifest directory is unfamiliar to me in a Metadata API-format project, but this is easy to change in a script if needed too.